# Glitched message on the top left corner over other app/desktop

Tags: windows, video

I have random issue under windows 11. Sometime some application messages are displayed and stuck on top left corner of my display. Those messages are over other app (like firefox, windows desktop, vlc, etc..) and do not disappear except after a reboot.

It's never the same app that displays message on the top left corner.

it's like a video glitch, but instead of displaying messages on the bottom right, it displays on top left.

I do not know if issue is coming from video, or the app that emits messages at the time.

here it's an example with the VPN app:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?